# pointers to 4 dimensional array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
    int **z[DIM0] = {yr,ys};  

____210________218_______226________234________242________  
|         |         |          |          |           |  
|  218    | 226     |          |          |           |  
|_________|_________|__________|__________|___________|_____  
     yr       *yr      xa[0]      xa[1]        xa[2]  ........  
                       ** yr
```

Hello,
        I am trying to figure out logic of why type pointer to pointer int were used for array z  elements type?

What happens when yr is assigned a type pointer to pointer int when array z is initialized. yr is and array of pointers to int. yr decays to pointer of int.
before array z is initialized.
But after z initializes yr is a pointer to pointer. Its no longer a pointer of type int due to decay? yr has and address what would address be after its converted to pointer to pointer of int as array z element. Could someone show memory diagram for yr, *yr, **yr?

after array z  initialization                                                                                    after yr declaration

```
____200______208_____216_______________256________________
|         |       |         |         |               |
|         |   256 |         |         |      yr[0]    |
|_________|_______|_________|_________|_______________|________
|    yr      *yr     **yr
```

confused I understand when you assign a type pointer to pointer to a pointer value. I understand
how memory is mapped.  Confused because yr has and address before initialization.
How is **yr created?

The following I follow.

```
int x = 5;
int *p = &x;
int **q = &p
```

```
___________240__________248________256_______
|                    |            |          |
|       248          |       256  |    5     |
|___________________ |___________ |__________|
         q                p             x
```

```
const int DIM = 2, DIM1 = 3, DIM2 = 4;
int xa[DIM2], xb[DIM2], xc[DIM2], xd[DIM2], xe[DIM2], xf[DIM2];
int *yr[DIM1] = {xa, xb, xc}, *ys[DIM1] = {xd, xe, xf};
**z[DIMO] = {yr, ys};
```

Comment: I think you have some formatting issues, the ascii art is broken and there is a `enter code here` in your question. It makes it very difficult to understand what you're asking.

Edit: oh wait, i can edit posts now, i'll try to see if i can fix that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: So, why did you call it a "4 dimensional array" in the title??? At this point I only see 3 dimensions.

Comment: Sorry its a 3 dimensional been working on four recently got confused.

Answer (score 1):

If all the data were allocated as one giant block like this:

```
int z[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
```

It would allocate a single contiguous array and you could
reference into it directly:

```
val= z[1][2][3];
```

This is what your diagrams describe. This only works iff `z[][][]`
was allocated in one fell swoop.

But it wasn't, and your diagram does not reflect the code.

It was allocated as many smaller subsets (xa,xb,xc,xd,xe,xf) which are
scattered around in memory.  That is why `yr[]` and `ys[]` need to be
pointers to the beginning of each set.  `yr[0]` points to `xa[0]`,
`yr[1]` points to `xb[0]`.  `yr[0]` points to an int, so it is
declared as `int *yr[]`.

And now yr and ys are also allocated independently. So `z[]` needs to
point to each of the sets of pointers to sets of integers. `z[0]`
points to `yr[0]` which points to `xa[0]` which is an int, so z is
declared as `int **z[]`.

Your diagram would be correct if it had 24 boxes scattered around
on the page with lots of arrows.

Comment: when yr was initialized its elements are type pointer to int. yr decays to a pointer to int?

Comment: `yr` most certainly does not *decay*. A *decay* is a lossy one-way conversion; the information lost is *never* recovered in a decay. `yr` is *implicitly converted* from an expression of array type to an expression of pointer type, where the pointer points to the first element of the array. The information lost *is* recovered once the evaluation of the expression occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure where you picked up the term "decays" -- perhaps you are confusing it with "dereferences"? The terms `*xa` and `xa[0]` are equivalent. The terms `xa` and `&xa[0]` are also equivalent. It might make more sense if yr were declared as `int *yr[DIM1]= { &xa[0] };` but you will never see it written that way.

Comment: when yr was initialized its elements are type pointer to int. yr decays to a pointer to int?  In array z initialization yr allocated as a pointer to pointer its no longer a pointer to int? This is where im confused what happens with yr initial decay type when yr was initialized and yr is included in array z initialization to a type pointer to pointer. Does it change its type? when z is initialized Does compiler assign a pointer to int to point to the initial pointer of memory value of yr(decay pointer address) when yr was initialized to have elements of type pointer to int?

Comment: *Does compiler assign a pointer to int to point to the initial pointer of memory value of yr* -- Yes, exactly right. Again, `&xa[0]` is a pointer to an int, and `xa` is just a shorter way of saying _exactly the same thing_. So there is no _decay_ involved, just two ways of specifying the same thing.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor "decay" is a common term for the implicit conversion you describe. It is lossy.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is lossy *for the period of evaluation*... Then the size information is miraculously recovered. That doesn't sound anywhere near as permanent as a *decay* to me.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor the information is never recovered . From the pointer you cannot recover the size information.

Comment: @MattMcNabb From the pointer you can't recover the information, sure... But that's not what "THE ARRAY DECAYS" says. This implies that the array undergoes a lossy transformation from which it can't return, which is of course nonsense.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor It means that the value of the expression denoting the array undergoes a lossy transformation.   We don't go into so much pedantic detail every time because it would be tedious and most people know what is meant.  You took the same shortcut yourself in saying "yr is implicitly converted".

Comment: Beating a dead horse, but Patrick was referring decay of the type not the data. I guess I can imagine some CS professor somewhere using the term to describe the loss of DIM1 when the array is cast to a pointer to an unknown number of int's. One must rely on apriori knowledge to know when to stop. This is why "smart pointers" were invented, which led to vectors, which led to C++, which led to Java. All a pointless exercise.

Comment: @MattMcNabb While *most people* don't often encounter problems with C (in fact, *most people* don't even want to learn C), we cater for those who do by being especially *pedantic*, as you describe it... Rather, I describe it as *explaining things thoroughly and correctly so that they don't misunderstand later on, and we don't have to repeat lessons*.

Comment: @TeasingDart Yes. It's a *decay of the type*, also known as a *conversion*, similar to the *decay of the type* in `int x = 0ULL;`... which is of course a *conversion*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, TeasingDart has a good point: None of these examples constitute a *4-dimensional array*. It's not a *3-dimensional array*, either, despite having three levels of indirection. An array is a single allocation.

There's one obvious reason that might explain why `z` wasn't declared as `int ***`, similarly to your `q`, `p` and `x` examples: `int ***z = {yr,ys};` produces an error, and the person who wrote this code knew no better than you. This would lead on to my main point here: Why would you choose to learn from such a resource?

If you want to declare a *three-dimensional array* for use in a particular function or block of code, declare it inside the function or block of code as TeasingDart did:

```
int z[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3];
```

Alternatively, if you expect to be returning the array and you want to use `malloc`, you could use something like the following in C:

```
typedef int_column[DIM2][DIM3];
int_column *foo = malloc(DIM1 * sizeof *foo);
```

... or of course *`std::vector`* in C++, which brings me to another point: It's probably not a good idea to tag C and C++, most of the time, when your question is really just a C question.

Notice how this is *still only one allocation*? That's an important aspect of arrays.

Comment: Well, it is not a built-in 3D array (by its memory layout), but it still can be referred to as a 3D array in a more generic sense. What we have there is a rather well-known idiom called *jagged array* (or *ragged array*). It is not really "jagged" in this case, but the technique is the same.

Comment: @AnT It's not an array. It's very important to make this distinction early, before they start using `qsort` and asking why their code is crashing (because they're treating one allocation as though it stores multiple allocations). Please don't defend the terminology, at least not in C...

Comment: No, this is an *array* and the terminology is extremely well-established. There will be no debate about this. Here's a canonical C FAQ link that describes this very technique for dynamically allocating multi-dimensional array: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html. Everybody understands the difference in semantics between a built-in multi-dimensional array and such pointer-based multi-dimensional array idiom. There's no confusion here.

Comment: @AnT c-faq doesn't define the C programming language... Can you come up with a more reputable resource, such as n1256 or n1570?

Comment: I don't care about "defining C programming language" at all. There's is no requirement to somehow restrict oneself to the terminology of "C programming language" when discussing C-specific topics, especially when it comes to well-established terms C language shareswith other areas of computer science. Moreover, comp.lang.c FAQ has the ultimate level of reputability. It is not possible to come up with something "more reputable".

Comment: @AnT If the terminology you speak of is "extremely well-established" as you say, then it should be in the C standard... but it isn't... and it isn't for a reason: It's harmful to describe this as a *multidimensional array*, especially considering **there are easier ways, involving less keystrokes *AND less allocations* to achieve the same end, *which will actually be a multidimensional array***...

Comment: "If the terminology you speak of is "extremely well-established" [...] then it should be in the C standard"... Er... I don't know what to make out of that. It just doesn't make sense to me. C standard is not a scrapbook.

Comment: @AnT Scrapbooks don't define terms; dictionaries do.